# i'm getting runtime error com.twlapps.goolarr E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main and my app crashes once i open it

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm getting runtime error and my app crashes when I run it

```
2020-03-29 12:40:22.942 9111-9111/com.twlapps.goolarr E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.twlapps.goolarr, PID: 9111
    java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
        at com.twlapps.goolarr.SigninFragment.onCreateView(SigninFragment.java:73)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentMana
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the problem is that you are trying to assign an AppCompatTextView to an EditText. Most likely the error occurs when findViewById () is fixed to fix either fix AppCompatTextView to EditText in your markup, or use AppCompatTextView